# How to override `lifecycle` configuration in a sub module in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a module in terraform, it looks like:

my-service:

```
module "api" {
  source                      = "../modules/base-service"
  ...
```

In the `base-service` module, it ignores `desired_count` for ECS service:

base-service:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
 ...
 desired_count = 1
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes   = ["desired_count"]
 }
}
```

Because of the `desired_count` is ignored, I can't override it from `my-service`. How can I override the setting for `desired_count`?

Comment: I am not able to see `my-service` resource in your code. are you referring to the `service` resource.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem you are facing if you take the desired count from a variable like below?

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
 ...
 desired_count = ${var.desired_count}
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes   = ["desired_count"]
 }
}
```

```
module "api" {
  source                      = "../modules/base-service"
  desired_count               = 5
  ...
}
```